# How to get the request body and headers in Curl format in latest Postman version v5.5.0?

Tags: rest, web-services, postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a working post API call in Postman. I am planning to call it through bash by using Curl script. How to convert my current request into Curl script?

Comment: You can get the full cURL request command line straight from Postman https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets

Comment: great, it's working, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Postman [`code`](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets) feature to generate snippets in various different languages.

This is a quick example showing the generated cURL snippet using the headers, request body etc.

[image: Code Snippet]

You can also do the reverse of this action with a cURL request, these can be imported into Postman from a file or the request can be pasted straight into the application in raw text form.

These option can be found in the `Import` section.

[image: Import cURL request]

Once imported, Postman will populate the different areas with the raw request data.

Comment: cURL code snippets generated by Postman will not show headers appended with `pm.request.headers.add` in a pre-request, just FYI.

Comment: It's never done that. The code snippets are created based on the static information in the request (URL, Auth, Headers and request body payload) . Anything that changes the request at runtime wouldn't be in there.